# TAniIndicator not animating while performing an action.

Tags: ios, delphi, animation, delphi-xe4

In my application, I have actions/buttons that are linked to queries that load new forms and populate tables with data. I would like to have an animated spinner animate while the queries load.

My current code has by default the TaniIndicator.visible/enabled properties set to false and then when the button is pressed to load the new form, the procedure begins by enabling both of those TaniIndicator properties, however, in my application, the spinner never shows and only is faint to see once the queries are finished and the new form is ready to appear. help  ?

Using Delphi xe4, developing an iOS application.

Comment: Perhaps this link is helpful, [`Problem with TAniIndicator`](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=68439)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just coded:

```
    application.processMessages
```

as the article suggested by @LU RD guides to...
Was no need to create another Thread.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you perform your query on the main thread, and UI updates is blocked while the query is executing. You should start indicator, detach a new background thread or queue,  launch task on that thread. Once it is done, switch back to main thread and hide or stop the indicator.